# Organising template functionality

Tags: php, silverstripe

Short and sweet, I have a controller extending `Page_Controller` and within contains loads of custom template functionality that I would like to "organise" and put this functionality into other files.

```
class BookingPage extends Page
{

}

class BookingPage_Controller extends Page_Controller
{
    public function getMyTemplateVar() {}
    public function MyTemplateVar2($param) {}
    // x 1000~ more
}
```

My question here, is there any way to create template functionality globally and not just within a particular `Page_Controller`?

My OCD is having a fit putting everything in a single file (controller is already 3432 lines long)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to accomplish this like so:

```
class BookingPage extends Page {}
class BookingPage_Controller extends \MyNamespace\Template\Functionality {}
```

**\MyNamespace\Template\Functionality**

```
namespace MyNamespace\Template;

class Functionality extends \Page_Controller {

    public function ExternalAPI() {
        return new \MyNamespace\Rooms\ExternalRoomDataAPI();
    }
}
```

**\MyNamespace\Rooms\ExternalRoomDataAPI**

```
namespace MyNamespace\Rooms;

class ExternalRoomDataAPI {
    public function HelloWorld() {
        $html = "Hello World";
        return $html;
    }
}
```

**MyTemplate.ss**

```
$ExternalAPI.HelloWorld
// result: Hello World
```

Am interested in knowing whether or not there is a cleaner way, you can literally extend and extend and extend to organise your functionality this way as long as your final class extends `Page_Controller` or create new objects and return them as their methods/variables are chainable indefinitely

Comment: You could use a "helper" singleton or traits. See http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.traits.php . Or move some of the methods to a extension if their context suits that better.